# Python LDA - Get multiple topics weight per document

Tags: python, lda, topic-modeling

I am using LDA to assign a topic to multiple documents. I have set LDA to a maximum of 4 possible topics. I have managed to assign a topic to each document and create CSV file with it.

Is it possible to get the weight each topic had for each document? I want something like this:
[image]

```
def get_words(dict, search_index):
    return list(dict.keys())[list(dict.values()).index(search_index)]


reviews_datasets = pd.read_csv('clean_reviews_esp.csv')

#creates voculabulary of reviews data
#receive an already cleaned review text (lemmatized and stop words removed)
count_vect = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.8, min_df=10)
doc_term_matrix = count_vect.fit_transform(reviews_datasets['cleaned_reviews'].values.astype('U'))
print(doc_term_matrix.shape)

#creates LDA to create topics with the probability distribution for each word in the vocabulary. 
#n_components means we want the vocabulary to be sorted in 4 topics (food,service,local,price)
LDA = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=4, random_state=42)
LDA.fit(doc_term_matrix)

i=0
for topic in LDA.components_:
    print(f'Top 10 words for topic #',i)
    top_topic_words = topic.argsort()[-10:]
    for x in top_topic_words:
        print(get_words(count_vect.vocabulary_,x))
    i+=1
    print('\n')

topic_values = LDA.transform(doc_term_matrix)
topic_values.shape
reviews_datasets['Topic'] = topic_values.argmax(axis=1)

reviews_datasets.to_csv('clean_reviews_with_topics.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Is this not topic_values? the documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html) says that it should return the document-topic distribution